# Selenium|Python Exception: "element not interactable" when uploading product images to wordpress

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing code that automatically uploads products to wordpress.

I use selenium (100.0.4896.88) with python (3.10).

I need to upload 2 types of product images (use the same code):

1. Production image
2. product gallery images

[2 types of product images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4e9n.png)

**1. Set product image (first code)**

```
  #1  open upload frame 
    driver.find_element_by_id("set-post-thumbnail").click()  #Click "set product image"
    time.sleep(10 ) #waiting open frame
    
  #2  open "dialog browser window"  
    driver.find_element_by_id("menu-item-upload").click() #Click tab "upload file"**-->CLICK OK**
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("browser.button.button-hero").click() #open "dialog browser window"
    time.sleep(5) #waiting dialog window open
    
  #3 Send path file   
    pyautogui.write(product_image_path)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(60 )#waiting upload image
    
  #4 add image
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("button.media-button.button-primary.button-large.media-button-select").click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

**2. Add product gallery images(second code - same the first code)**

```
  #1  open upload frame 
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("add_product_images.hide-if-no-js").click()#Click "Add product gallery images"
    time.sleep(10)#waiting open frame
    
  #2  open "dialog browser window"  
    driver.find_element_by_id("menu-item-upload").click() #Click tab "upload file" ***--> CAN'T CLICK***
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("browser.button.button-hero").click() #open "dialog browser window"
    time.sleep(5) #waiting dialog window open

  #3 Send path file     
    pyautogui.write(gallery_images_path) #path of File
    pyautogui.press('enter')    
    time.sleep(60)#waiting upload image
    
  #4 add image    
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("button.media-button.button-primary.button-large.media-button-select").click()
```

[Click tab "upload file"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk7v5.png)

With both types of images, use the same upload frame. The code for the 2 uploads is the same.

When uploading "Production image" (the first code) it works fine but the 2nd time uploading :"product gallery images" (the second code) doesn't work. Selenium can't click to tab "Upload file".

```
driver.find_element_by_id("menu-item-upload").click() #Click tab "upload file"
```

**Exception:**

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.88)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00C17413+2389011]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BA9F61+1941345]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A9C520+836896]
        Ordinal0 [0x00ACA1F3+1024499]
```

I tried running these 2 codes separately, they both work fine.

I also changed the location of the 2 codes but it only works for the first code, the second one doesn't work.

I have added win wait driver , use Queryselector or XPATH but they are not working.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Upload files"]'))).click()
```

Please help me.
Thank !

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue and can`t manage to get around it, did you found a solution? The best i can imagine right now is to wait for the user to click it, but is not the intended.

Comment: also, you can skip some steps instead of clicking the button to open de file dialog just do somthing like this: 
```insert_keys_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']", image_path, driver)```

Comment: def insert_keys_by_xpath(xpath, keys, driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).send_keys(keys)

Answer (score 0):

minh-thiện I finally solved it, in my case it was a problem with the selector, because I was using just the id of the element which should normally works fine but in this case I searched for the element with that ID and there were more than one in the html so the solution was to use the full XPath to the element I wanted to click instead of the xpath with just the id.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Cheers